# Strange behavior of accumE with Event (UI a -> UI a)

Tags: haskell, user-interface, threepenny-gui

I'm experimenting with threepenny-gui, trying to learn the FRP interface. I want to avoid all explicit shared state using accumE/accumB, instead of IORef:s. I have four different signals (start, stop, timer, reset) which all affect a global state and the user interface. I'm using `accumE w $ concatenate <$> unions [e0, e1, e2, e3]` to make the events share the same state `w`. Here is a short snippet which captures the essence of it (with only one signal):

```
data World = World { intW :: Int , runW :: UI () }

main :: IO ()
main = startGUI defaultConfig setup

setup :: Window -> UI ()
setup _ = do
    (e0, fire) <- liftIO  UI.newEvent
    let e0' = action <$ e0
    e <- accumE (World 0 (return ())) e0'
    onEvent e $ \w -> void $ runW w
    replicateM_ 5 . liftIO $ fire ()
    where
        action :: World -> World
        action w = w { intW = succ $ intW w
                     , runW = liftIO . print $ intW w }
```

This seems to work fine (although I wonder if it is sane). However, if I instead change the event to have type `Event (UI World -> UI World)` (and remove the runW field), things go haywire:

```
data World = World { intW :: Int } deriving (Show)

main :: IO ()
main = startGUI defaultConfig setup

setup :: Window -> UI ()
setup _ = do
    (e0, fire) <- liftIO UI.newEvent
    let e0' = action <$ e0
    e <- accumE (return (World 0)) e0'
    onEvent e void
    replicateM_ 5 . liftIO $ fire ()
    where
        action :: UI World -> UI World
        action world = do
            w <- world
            let w' = w { intW = succ $ intW w }
            liftIO $ print w'
            return w'
```

It seems that all UI actions somehow get accumulated, and executed an increasing number of times with each event! I thought accumE was like a fold, where the accumulating state is replaced unless explicitly accumulated. What is the proper/best way of dealing with this problem in general?

Comment: This would be easier to answer if you could provide some runnable code - it's a little hard for me to follow this question.

Comment: Sorry, yes I'll add some running code. Nice homepage btw.

Comment: The code does exactly what may not be your intention: `accumE` accumulates a value of type `UI World` by repeatedly applying the `action` function. You would get the same result with a fold.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure I quite understand. Before posting, I tested with a fold and it worked as I intended: https://gist.github.com/bakerjonas/5e63437c87d9eea349b0

Comment: @Heinrich: Is it the statefulness of the RWST monad which kicks in? My fold example is over the plain IO monad. More generally, is my scheme for handling shared state and UI actions sound, or is there a better way?

Comment: @JonasJuselius No, you just have a basic misunderstanding of how event accumulation differs from a fold. It's hard for me to explain here, but the thing is that `onEvent` will execute the accumulated action *for each* event occurrence, whereas the action accumulated by the test `fold` you wrote will be executed only once.

Comment: @JonasJuselius: In general, mixing `UI` actions and FRP the way you do is not a good idea. Rather, state should be distributed over several Behaviors and Events. `accumE` can only perform pure state updates, no side effects. At the moment, it's not possible to do state updates that have side effects, this would require dynamic event switching which Threepenny does not implement yet.

Comment: Thank you @HeinrichApfelmus for your valuable comments. I'm probably missing something, but if `accumE` accumulates the full event (action) history, doesn't it cause a space leak? Anyway, I'll look deeper into the `accumE` implementation, and see if I can figure it out.

Comment: Perhaps a better way of dealing with shared state (or time/event dependent values, if you like) is to store them in `ReadWriteAttrs` and then use `sink` to update them when the corresponding `Behavior` changes? Then I can let the timer event handler update all UI elements which needs update, based on the (updated) attributes.